# LINQ Query with dynamic where clause based on search criteria that is NOT part of the returned object

Tags: linq

I have an AlumniRecords table with 60+ columns.  I created an AlumniSearchResults class that only contains the handful of fields I need for display in a table of search results.  This is an MVC2 app so I want to keep the objects clean (in other words, I don't want to pass the 60+ field object to my view).  I am trying to build my AlumniSearchResult as part of my query against AlumniRecords.  This worked fine BUT I also want to dynamically add where clauses only if they are in the SearchCriteria object - the problem is my search criteria are not necessarily in the results object (for instance lastname).

FIRST TRY:

```
var alumniRecords = iuaaOlcEntities.AlumniRecords;

        if (searchCriteria.lastname != null) alumniRecords.Where(ar => ar.lastname == searchCriteria.lastname);

        return alumniRecords.Select(ar => new AlumniSearchResult
        {
            person_id = ar.person_id,
            fullname  = ar.fullname,
            city      = ar.city,
            state     = ar.state,
            emp_name  = ar.emp_name,
            emp_title = ar.emp_title
        });
```

This just ignores the where clause for lastname.  I cannot chain the where clause after select because AlumniSearchResult has no lastname field.

SECOND TRY:

```
            var searchResults = from ar in iuaaOlcEntities.AlumniRecords
                            where ar.lastname == searchCriteria.lastname
                            select new AlumniSearchResult
                            {
                                person_id = ar.person_id,
                                fullname  = ar.fullname,
                                city      = ar.city,
                                state     = ar.state,
                                emp_name  = ar.emp_name,
                                emp_title = ar.emp_title
                            };
```

This format works but I have a dozen search criteria and only want to add "ar.lastname == searchCriteria.lastname" searchCriteria.lastname has a value.

Any thoughts for this LINQ newb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    var alumniRecords = iuaaOlcEntities.AlumniRecords.AsQueryable();

    if (searchCriteria.lastname != null) 
        alumniRecords = alumniRecords.Where(ar => ar.lastname == searchCriteria.lastname);

    return alumniRecords.Select(ar => new AlumniSearchResult
    {
        person_id = ar.person_id,
        fullname  = ar.fullname,
        city      = ar.city,
        state     = ar.state,
        emp_name  = ar.emp_name,
        emp_title = ar.emp_title
    });
```

Comment: Thanks!  I did not see the ".AsQueryable()" you added and got a cast error so I fixed it like this:
IQueryable<AlumniRecord> alumniRecords = iuaaOlcEntities.AlumniRecords;

Any advantage/disadvantage to this approach?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update alumniRecords with the return value from the call to Where:

```
if (searchCriteria.lastname != null) {
  alumniRecords = alumniRecords.Where(ar => ar.lastname == searchCriteria.lastname);
}
```

Comment: Thanks - it was a "Doh!" moment.  Probably more to come :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something with the results of your where statement in your first example. Try assigning it back to your `alumniRecords` variable.

Or, in your second example try something like:

```
where (searchCriteria.lastname == null || ar.lastname == searchCriteria.lastname)
```

This way, your criteria will get short-circuited if it is null.